# PCB edge connectors for either board to board and screw terminal

Tags: screw-terminal, edge-connector, power-connector

I am at the final stage of design a pcb and I am looking for a connector to power it (2 pins, more would be also ok).
It has 2 use cases:
I could be either used as a standalone product, in this case a screw terminal would be perfect,
or it can be used in a rack, and in this case an edge connector at the back of the rack would provide power.
What I cannot find, if they exist, are two edge connectors of the same "family" or compatible, one to be soldered on a second pcb to accept my board at 90 degrees, and a second to connect the pcb edge to wires possibly with screw, spring...
Current requirements are quite low, a couple of watts at 48Vdc.

Comment: The [Phoenix Contact 1830715](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/pxc-oc-itemdetail-pdf-web/eshop?lineItemType=LineItem&UID=1830715) was the first thing I found that could work as a backplane connector -- compatible board connectors and free hanging connectors exist, but the cable will have an "industrial" feel to it. I largely agree with @Fredled that two connectors are probably easier and cheaper.

Comment: Every dish washer I opened used card edge to cable connectors. I don't know a part number though...

Comment: The standard for home appliances is called RAST. Unfortunately I was not able to find a compatible tht connector. About the industrial feel... It's a product designed to go in a rack, with metal case and for telco use... Not a problem with industrial looks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my search.
The connector family is the classic COMBICON from Phoenix Contact.
On the product I will use for power ingress these:

COMBICON MSTBA

[image: COMBICON MSTBA]

For wired connection the classic mating component:

COMBICON MSTB

[image: COMBICON MSTB]

And finally on the rack, to power the board while inserted these inverted terminal blocks:

COMBICON ICV

[image: COMBICON ICV]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it exists a common connector for both solutions. When inserting a device into a rack, the pin size and diameter must match the female socket very exactly.
When you attach wires, you can't use the same technique because the wires can have different diameters and qualities, and will be usually smaller than pins. That's why with wires you need screws or springs.

You could use this type of connector which is designed for wires. Then adapting the rack terminal PCB with right angle pin connectors, spaced at 4mm pitch so that they can enter the wire connectors. But you would need find such pins long enough to enter the connector deeply enough. And it would be quiet experimental.
Board to board manufacturers may offer you ready solutions if you buy some quantities.
https://www.we-online.com/catalog/en/em/connectors/led_connectors/wr-leco_wire_to_board/

IMO it's more simple to duplicate the connectors: One for the rack, the other for the wires. It will be more reliable and cheaper than a customized solution. For only two pins, it's no big deal.

Comment: I also though of duplicating connectors, but this will create the problem that when in use with wires it will leave the rack contact exposed

Comment: @user1937747 I don't think it's a problem to get these pins exposed. But as I can see, you have found the solution.